# if a file has windows line endings change it to linux line endings else do nothing

Tags: linux, file, line, line-endings

I am looking to write an if statement if a file has windows line endings change it to linux line endings else do nothing

this is the file with windows line endings `^M` or `\r\n`

```
$ cat -v  file.csv | head
"Rec_Open_Date","MSISDN","IMEI","Data_Volume_Bytes","Device_Manufacturer","Device_Model","Product_Description"^M
"2015-10-06","427","060","137765","Samsung Korea","Samsung SM-G900I","$39 Plan"^M
"2015-10-06","592","620","0","Apple Inc","Apple iPhone 6 (A1586)","PREPAY  STD - TRIAL - #16"^M
"2015-10-06","007","290","0","Apple Inc","Apple iPhone 6 (A1586)","PREPAY PLUS - $0 -"^M
"2015-10-06","592","050","48836832","Apple Inc","Apple iPhone 5S (A1530)","Talk and Text Connect Flexi Plan"^M
"2015-10-06","409","720","113755347","Samsung Korea","Samsung SM-G360G","$29 CARRYOVER PLAN"^M
"2015-10-06","742","620","19840943","Apple Inc","Apple iPhone S (A1530)","PREPAY STD - $0 - #2"^M
"2015-10-06","387","180","0","HUAWEI Technologies Co Ltd","HUAWEI HUAWEI G526-L11","PREPAY STD - $1 - #4"^M
"2015-10-06","731","570","2258243","Samsung Korea","Samsung SM-N910U","Business Freedom"^M
"2015-10-06","556","910","13332272","Samsung Korea","Samsung GT-I9505","$49 Plan"^M
```

this is the code to convert it to linux line endings `\n`:

```
  $ awk 'sub("\r$", "")' file.csv | head | cat -v
    "Rec_Open_Date","MSISDN","IMEI","Data_Volume_Bytes","Device_Manufacturer","Device_Model","Product_Description"
    "2015-10-06","427","060","137765","Samsung Korea","Samsung SM-G900I","$39 Plan"
    "2015-10-06","592","620","0","Apple Inc","Apple iPhone 6 (A1586)","PREPAY  STD - TRIAL - #16"
    "2015-10-06","007","290","0","Apple Inc","Apple iPhone 6 (A1586)","PREPAY PLUS - $0 -"
    "2015-10-06","592","050","48836832","Apple Inc","Apple iPhone 5S (A1530)","Talk and Text Connect Flexi Plan"
    "2015-10-06","409","720","113755347","Samsung Korea","Samsung SM-G360G","$29 CARRYOVER PLAN"
    "2015-10-06","742","620","19840943","Apple Inc","Apple iPhone S (A1530)","PREPAY STD - $0 - #2"
    "2015-10-06","387","180","0","HUAWEI Technologies Co Ltd","HUAWEI HUAWEI G526-L11","PREPAY STD - $1 - #4"
    "2015-10-06","731","570","2258243","Samsung Korea","Samsung SM-N910U","Business Freedom"
    "2015-10-06","556","910","13332272","Samsung Korea","Samsung GT-I9505","$49 Plan"
```

this is my basic if statemnt, I am just not sure how to get a true or false from the line ending: **Can anyone advise how I would do this?**

```
if [ $1 -gt 100 ]  ## line ending =^M
then
awk 'sub("\r$", "")' file.csv   ## remove the windows line endings
fi
```

note for self, as far as I know 
windows line endings can be `^M`, `\r\n` or `CRLF`.
linux line endings can be `\n` `LF`.

---

### **EDIT1**

think [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/163481/a-command-to-print-only-last-3-characters-of-a-string) is what I am looking for.

```
$  eol=$(cat -v  file.csv | head -n1 | grep -o '..$')
$  echo "$eol"
^M
$ if [ "$eol" = "^M" ]; then echo "true"; fi
true
$ if [ "$eol" = "^M" ]; then echo "true"; else echo "false"; fi
true
```

where I would put `awk 'sub("\r$", "")' file.csv` as my true statement

Comment: What for? If the file already has *nix line endings then the `awk` command is a no-op.

Comment: if you just need to convert line endings, then see `man dos2unix`

Comment: And ^M, CR (from CRLF) and "\r" describe the same character.

Comment: some configurations of the `file` utility will report something like 'MS-Windows text file'. Check your verison with `file file.csv` . Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Use `vim` to change file format to Unix, e.g.

```
vim file.txt <<EOF
:set fileformat=unix
ZZ
EOF
```

If the file is already in Unix format the above code will leave the file unchanged.

Comment: I should have mentioned but, can that be done in a bash script

Comment: @HatteickNZ the above was written for you to add to a bash script. The EOF markers are so you can pass input to view finalized in your script.

Comment: This will not work with vi, only with vim. If it seems to work with vi it's because your vi is a vim [cylon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylon_%28Battlestar_Galactica%29#Humanoid_cylons).

Comment: Thanks @user9645 - I have updated my answer to reflect that the answer is based on `vim` and not `vi`.